# VueJS: Change placeholder after form submission

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I have like to clear the placeholder of a form after form submission.  However my code below doesn't seem work. It doesn't clear the input textfield.

```
data() {
  return {
    placeholder: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VooQbNHP44M",
  };
},
```

---

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitVideo">
 <div class="flex">
   <input
     type="text"
     :placeholder="placeholder"
     v-model="yturl"
   />
```

---

```
async submitVideo() {
   this.placeholder = "";
}
```

---

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to clear the *placeholder* and not the actual *value*? Do you mean `this.yturl = ''` instead?

Comment: you might also need to clear v-model yturl

Comment: oh, yes, both of you are right...you might want to put it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async submitVideo() {
  this.placeholder = "";  // clears placeholder value
  this.yturl = "";  // clears input value
}
```